# Topic not able to receive message

Tags: jms, spring-jms, jms-topic

I have a non durable Topic client which is supposed to receive messages asynchronously using a listener. 
When message is published on Topic, i can see on admin console that message is published and consumed but my client never receives it.

Client is able to establish connection properly as i can track it on console.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Did some more analysis and found that issue is with API used for connection.
I was able to listen to messages when i use following code:

```
TopicConnection conn;
TopicSession session = conn.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic(monacoSubscriberEmsTopic);
conn.start();
tsubs = session.createSubscriber(topic); 

tsubs.setMessageListener(listener);
```

But when i use following code then it doesn't work:

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = createMessageListenerContainer();

private DefaultMessageListenerContainer createMessageListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setClientId(clientID);
    listenerContainer.setDestinationName(destination);
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(minConsumerCount);
    listenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConsumerCount);
    listenerContainer.setPubSubDomain(true);
    listenerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeModeName(sessionAcknowledgeMode);
    if (messageSelector != null)
      listenerContainer.setMessageSelector(messageSelector);
    listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
    return listenerContainer;
  }
listenerContainer.initialize();
listenerContainer.start();
```

What is wrong with second approach?

Comment: Does the subscriber is subscribing to the same topic as that of publisher?

Comment: Yes it is, i have checked that. Main problem is that message is getting consumed!!

Comment: any TTL property on the message that causes it to expire immediately?  any filtering on the consumer that causes the listener to not get it?

Comment: Added some edits to my post with new info.